# htaccess rewrite find part of the slug and remove it

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have posts like so:

```
http://example.com/blog/post-title
```

I want to convert this to

```
http://example.com/post-title
```

Using htaccess

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/blog/([^\s\?]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, you can indicate **two** *capture groups* (using parentheses) and only return the second of the two groups.

**Example:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(blog)/(.+) http://example.com/$2

</IfModule>
```

The rewrite rule works as follows:

**If...**

- the url starts with `blog`
- followed by `/`
- followed by *at least one or more characters*

then rewrite the URL so that the domain is followed by a `/` and then the *one or more characters* that were captured in the second capture group.

**N.B.** *You won't need an `[R=301]` flag since providing a full redirect (ie. a redirect starting with the `http://` or `https://` protocol) implicitly indicates that this will be a **301 Redirect**.*

Comment: This still not working for me, not sure if it's my site or the code.. I'm trying clearing the cache and saving permalinks

Comment: Works on another installation, but not the main site. Thanks, I'll figure this out.

Comment: Just a tip (although it may not be relevant here) - if you're using extended character sets, do _not_ save your `.htaccess` file with `UTF-8` encoding since this can mean that your `.htaccess` file gets ignored (I've never yet figured out why - something to do with _Byte Order Mark (BOM)_). Generally, I save `.htaccess` as ASCII via the encoding `Western (Windows 1252)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I put that in my notes. The issue wasn't with the htaccess file, it did throw 500 error when I made mistakes, but it turns out that I had to add `[L]` at the end ¯\_(ツ)_/¯